# ndb_restore return error: Could not alloc node id at xx.xx.xx.xx port 1186

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I am very newbie with MySQL Cluster (NDB-Cluster).
I try to restore cluster from backup file.
But I get this error, please help:

Command:

```
ndb_restore --ndb_connectstring=xx.xx.xx.xx --nodeid=2 --restore_meta --backupid=3 --backup_path=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/BACKUP/BACKUP-3 --disable-indexes
```

And error:

```
Nodeid = 2
Backup Id = 3
backup path = /var/lib/mysql-cluster/BACKUP/BACKUP-3
Configuration error: Error: Could not alloc node id at xx.xx.xx.xx port 1186: Connection done from wrong host ip xx.xx.xx.xx.
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to restore MySQL NDB cluster using ndb_restore utility as well, and met with the exactly same problem.

My solution is turn to use MySQL Cluster Manager (MCM) for restore instead, which is demostrated in this page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-manager/1.4/en/mcm-using-backup-restore-basic.html

Basically it uses the 'restore cluster' child-command provided by MCM utility to restore from a certain BACKUP made by ndb_mgm before. For more on how to use this command, check following page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-backup-using-management-client.html

A key step which is missing in the tutorial (the first offical MySQL link I posted), is to add a vacant ndbapi process so that you can perform restore operation (note to use a process ID which hasn't been used by any other NDB node in this cluster):

```
mcm> ADD PROCESS -R ndbapi:55@* myclustera;
+----------------------------+
| Command result             |
+----------------------------+
| Process added successfully |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)
```

Otherwise you'll come up with following error when trying with restore:

```
mcm> restore cluster --backupid=1 myclustera;
ERROR 5201 (00MGR): Unable to perform restore - no vacant ndbapi slots in config for cluster myclustera
```

Reason why above step is essential is clarified in this doc:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-manager/1.4/en/mcm-restore-cluster.html

> In order to restore a backup using restore cluster, the cluster must
> have an unused slot for an ndbapi process in its configuration.
> Otherwise, the command fails with the error Unable to perform restore -
> no vacant ndbapi slots in config for cluster cluster_name. See Adding Free Processes, for information on how to add a free ndbapi
> slot to your cluster.

The problem you came up with, is caused by you didn't create the vacant ndbapi process before restoring.